# How to remove EXIF data from image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, image, exif

I read in a file from an HTML file input. For iOS I can take a picture from the camera. The problem is that if you take the picture with the camera the content will include EXIF data(at least if I read the file content with the FileReader API).

> I can't use canvas cropping if the image includes EXIF data. Because
>   the image get destroyed every time I call `.toDataURL()`. My guess is
>   it doesn't recognize EXIF data and don't know how to crop a image with
>   EXIF data.
>
> The file content is being base64 encoded by
>   `FileReader.readAsDataURL()`. And I insert it into  img.src.
>
> The cropping is done by drawing a new image with `ctx.drawImage(...)` based in the old image
>   and  I finally got the new image data with `c.toDataURL()`.

So my question how do I remove EXIF data using javascript?

Comment: Maybe show how you are doing toDataUrl? I don't think canvas would have any issues with what you are doing.

Comment: @Woho87 I'm assuming the original thing is a _File_ or _Blob_ that doesn't have a _URL_ of it's own, right? Your issue may actually be caused by the importing into the canvas from the base64 url'd image, not exporting from it. Try `yourImgSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(yourFile);` instead, then import that into the canvas.

Comment: there should not be any exif in the canvas output...

Answer (score 5):

Note, you wrote:

> **the image get destroyed**

I think that problem is not in EXIF data. I think you have the [iOS canvas limitation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15):

> The maximum size for a canvas element is 3 megapixels for devices with
>   less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or
>   equal than 256 MB RAM.

This limits don't throw any errors, so then you will try to render or read 6MB image you will get a broken blob/dataURL string and so on. And you will think that File API is broken, canvas methods toDataURL/toBlob are broken, and you will be right. But bugs aren't in browser, this is a system limitation.

There known libs that fix iOS limitations:

- [Javascript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#ios-scaling-fixes)
- [ios-imagefile-megapixel](https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel)